# Flutter/Dart CustomScrollView issue with scrolling

Tags: flutter

Hi Guys i wonder if anybody has an answer to my issue. I have a CustomScrollView  which has several SliverToBoxAdapter inside it several PagedGridView (from the package infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart)

When the homepage is loaded the it seems that when i scroll up in the PagedGridView that the SliverPersistentHeader does not move up and  SliverToBoxAdapter(categoriesWidgetSection) does not collapse.

```
// BUILD of homepage
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            centerTitle: true,
            expandedHeight: 100,
            // expandedHeight: 100.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25,top: 30,bottom: 10),
              expandedTitleScale: 1,
              title: searchBar(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: categoriesWidgetSection(),
          ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
              minHeight: 60.0, // Adjust the minimum height as needed
              maxHeight: 60.0, // Adjust the maximum height as needed
              child: headerPageView(),
            ),
            pinned: true, // This will make it sticky
          ),
            // child containing 3 PagingAdvertisement class
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: productsInPageViews()),
        ],
    );
  }
```

```
 Widget productsInPageViews() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 1000, // Set the desired height for your PageView
          child: PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (value) {
              _pageNumber.value = value;
            },
            itemCount: 3,
            // Adjust the number of pages
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              switch (index) {
                case 0:
                  return PagingAdvertisement(pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 10,searchQuery: SearchQuery()) ; // This scrolling doesn't trigger the parent scrolling 
                case 1:
                  return PagingAdvertisement(pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 10,searchQuery: SearchQuery()) ;
                case 2:
                  return PagingAdvertisement(pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 10,searchQuery: SearchQuery()) ;
                default:
                  return SizedBox();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

PagingAdvertisement class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';

class PagingAdvertisement extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageIndex;
  final int pageSize;
  final SearchQuery searchQuery;

  PagingAdvertisement(
      {Key? key, required this.pageIndex, required this.pageSize, required this.searchQuery})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PagingAdvertisementState createState() => _PagingAdvertisementState();
}

class _PagingAdvertisementState extends State<PagingAdvertisement> {
  final PagingController<int,
      Advertisement> _pagingController = PagingController(firstPageKey: 1);
  final AdvertisementService _advertisementService = new AdvertisementService();
  final CategoryService _categoryService = new CategoryService();
  late List<Category> _categories;

  Future<List<Advertisement>> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    return _advertisementService.fetchAdvertisements(pageKey);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCategories();
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey).then((items) {
        _pagingController.appendPage(items, pageKey + 1);
      });
    });
  }

  void fetchCategories() async {
    _categories = await _categoryService.getCategories();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PagedGridView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        pagingController: _pagingController,
        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Advertisement>(
                itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                  return AdBoxCompact2(advertisement: item, category: _categories
                      .where((element) => element.id == item.categoryId)
                      .first);
                }
            ),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2
        ));
  }
}
```